# KeyError ['date'] - Python fixer.io

Tags: python, fixer.io

I'm starting over with fixerio, I have this code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
date = parsed["date"]
print("Date:", date, "\n")

rates = parsed["rates"]

for currency, rate in rates.items():
    print(currency, "= USD", rate)
```

Every time I run it, it throws:

```
C:\usio>python fixerio.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fixerio.py", line 9, in <module>
    date = parsed["date"]
KeyError: 'date'
```

Problem is, I don't get how can I "declare" this date thing, I mean, it obviously lacks some kind of declaration.

Also, talking about `fixer.io`, do You think is better with the `requests` module approach?

Or should the `fixerio` python module be used?

PS = I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick print of the output shows that the api is broken

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
print(parsed)
```

> {'0':
>   '#################################################################################################################################', '1': '#

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the `url` in your browser you can see they have  put up a notice

```
{
  "0": "#################################################################################################################################",
  "1": "#                                                                                                                               #",
  "2": "# IMPORTANT - PLEASE UPDATE YOUR API ENDPOINT                                                                                   #",
  "3": "#                                                                                                                               #",
  "4": "# This API endpoint is deprecated and has now been shut down. To keep using the Fixer API, please update your integration       #",
  "5": "# to use the new Fixer API endpoint, designed as a simple drop-in replacement.                                                  #",
  "6": "# You will be required to create an account at https://fixer.io and obtain an API access key.                                   #",
  "7": "#                                                                                                                               #",
  "8": "# For more information on how to upgrade please visit our Github Tutorial at: https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer#readme          #",
  "9": "#                                                                                                                               #",
  "a": "#################################################################################################################################"
}
```

So the key doesn't  exist.